# Initializing const c++ class without constructor

Tags: c++, constructor, c++03

I have a class which is used in a union, and therefore cannot have a (*non-trivial*) constructor.   I need to create a const instance of the class, can this be done?

i.e.:

```
 class Foo {
     // no constructors...
     private:
         int i;
 };

 union {
     Foo foo;
     Bar bar;
 } FooBar;

 const Foo defaultFoo = ???
```

Comment: Since the C++11 standard you can have instances of objects with non-trivial constructors. See e.g. [this `union` reference for details](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/union).

Comment: Unfortunately,  I'm using an older version of C++, which doesn't support constructors in unions.

Comment: Do the members have to be private?

Comment: I definitely prefer private members...   In reality it's a fairly large and complicated class...

Comment: You could have a static member function that returns an instance of `Foo`. No explicit constructors means you should still have a compiler-provided copy-constructor to use. `static Foo createFoo(int i) { Foo f; f.i = i; return f; } ... const Foo defaultFoo = Foo::createFoo(1234);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can copy-construct it from the result of a function:

```
static Foo configureDefaultFoo()
{
    Foo f; // not const
    f.setI(42); // call non-const member functions
    return f;
}

const Foo defaultFoo = configureDefaultFoo();
```

Note that although this results in an object that is `const`, it is dynamic initialization not static, and so it can suffer from the static initialization order fiasco (same would be true if calling a non-trivial constructor, only aggregate initialization would avoid the fiasco).